# The Second Derivative of an Image Using the Sobel Filter

Tags: image-processing, derivative, gradient, kernel

For computing the Harris corner detector, I want to calculate $I_{xy}$ and $I_{xy}$. Obtaining $I_x$ and $I_y$ are clear for me. But what about the second order derivatives?

[This](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/10622/11856) and [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/73214/11856) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56048672/1043882) posts say I have to do convolution operation twice:

$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} f = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f \right) = k_x \ast \left(  k_y \ast f \right) = \left( k_x \ast k_y \right) \ast f
$$

But [here](https://sbme-tutorials.github.io/2020/cv/presentations/week04.html#46) and also [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/63684/11856), I saw it can be done by element-wise operations:

```
Ixx = np.multiply(Ix, Ix) 
Iyy = np.multiply(Iy, Iy)
Ixy = np.multiply(Ix, Iy)
```

Which one is correct for doing Harris corner detector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$I_{xx}$ is not the same as $I_x^2$, and likewise $I_{xy}$ is not the same as $I_x I_y$.
The first is a product of two first order derivatives, the second is a second order derivative.

The Harris corner detector is based on the [structure tensor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_tensor), which is compose of the products of the first order derivatives. Follow the second set of links you found.

The second order derivatives from the [Hessian matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix), which can also be used to detect points of interest, but is not used in the Harris corner detector.